# How to listen for QDynamicPropertyChangeEvent in Qt to detect property change?

Tags: c++, qt

I need to update something based on Qt `QObject` dynamic property change. Dynamic properties are those `QVariant` values indexed by string names - can be set to any `QObject`.

Originally I was about to simply override `setProperty` method on my `QObject` sub-class, but as I read the [documentation on `setProperty`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#setProperty), I noticed this:

> Changing the value of a dynamic property causes a [`QDynamicPropertyChangeEvent`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdynamicpropertychangeevent.html) to be sent to the object.

Well, that's nice, but I remember that I already looked in the past and found no signal for that event in `QObject`. I looked again and [it's indeed not there](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#signals).

So through what means is that event sent and how do I catch it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just subclass your `QObject` subclass and override `event`:

```
class MyObject : public SomeQObjectSubclass
{
protected:
    bool event(QEvent *e) override {
        if (e->type() == QEvent::DynamicPropertyChange) {
            QDynamicPropertyChangeEvent *pe = static_cast<QDynamicPropertyChangeEvent *>(e);
            // do something with it
            return true; // if you handled it and want to stop further handling
        }
        return SomeQObjectSubclass::event(e); // don't forget this
    }
}
```

See also [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/eventsandfilters.html).

Comment: Thanks! I wonder: do you have any idea why are they not using normal signal/slot pattern like everywhere else? Until now, I was not even aware there's another event mechanism.

Comment: There's a semantic difference between events and signals. The linked docs about the Qt Object Model should explain it. Basically: an event is low-level and targeted to a specific object ("mouse button pressed down delivered to the widget under the cursor"). A signal is high-level and broadcasted to the world ("mouse button has been pressed down and released => that's a click => emit the `clicked` signal to the world").

Comment: This is an event because it's interesting for the object in question. If you want to turn it into a signal, add the signal and emit it from `event`.

Comment: Hey I just noticed weird thing. Your solution works, but stops paint events (and possibly others) from working. That even happens if I make a dummy overload like this: `bool MyClass::event(QEvent *e)  {return QObject::event(e);}` Maybe a Qt bug? Don't you have any experience with that?

Comment: Oops, "of course" you should use the right base class in there. Fixing the code.

Comment: Yeah, just figured it out as well.